# How to calculate the polygon area and create a column of results in R

Tags: r, polygon, area, calculate-values

I'm working with shapefile in R and I need to calculate the polygons' area that I created by Gdiference function, So ,now I need to create a column with the size of  freshly  polygons created, because after that I need take out the small polygons which are not important to my academic research

I didn't use any function yet.

Comment: Take a look at ?rgeos::gArea

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Can you provide data for an example? Anyways, try this:

```
library(sf)
f <- st_read("shapefile.shp")
f$area <- st_area(f) #Take care of units
```

Best

Comment: It worked, but when I tried to use the shapefile function, returns me a error.            Error in (function (classes, fdef, mtable)  : 
  unable to find an inherited method for function ‘shapefile’ for signature ‘"sf"’

Comment: The raster::shapefile function is for reading data from on-disk files and returns a polygon object using the `sp` package's methods for representing spatial data in R (in this case, a SpatialPolygonsDataFrame). If you want to convert the sf polygon dataframe back to an SPDF, use `as(f, 'Spatial')`. To go from sp to sf, you can use `sf::st_as_sf(f)`. If all you want to do is write your result back to disk, you don't have to convert to sp first - just use `sf::st_write()`.

Answer (score 5):

Use `sf::st_area`

Pro tip: `dplyr::mutate` allows you to do multiple computations at once. For example, if your shapefile units are in meters, you can easily compute the area in acres or hectares as well.

```
library(sf); library(tidyverse)
p <- st_read("polygon.shp")


p %>% 
  dplyr::mutate(area_meters = st_area(p),
                # 1 m2 = 0.0.000247105 acres
                area_acres = area_meters * 0.0.000247105,
                # 1m2 = 0.0001 hectares
                area_hectares = area_meters * 0.0001)
```

Comment: The result of `sf::st_area` is a unit class object so, you can simply use `units::set_units` to change the unit to something else eg., `set_units(st_area(p), "acre")` and not have to remember conversion factors.